# Channel URL incompatible with caller app

Tags: windows-8, push-notification

I am trying to write a Push notification sample in Windows8 as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx. I have associated my app to the store and received the notification channel for the app. But when I pass it to my cloud service (which is just a website which would get the channel URI from the query string) to get the access token, the HTTP request always times out. But it succeeds when I try to get the access token from within the app using the SID and SecretKey. When i tried to use http://31daysofwindows8.com/push for testing, i received an exception "Channel URL incompatible with caller app". Per my understanding, the cloud service does not need to be associated with a store or configured for Push notifications, and all that it needs is the SID and the SecretKey to get the access token. Not sure if my assumption/understanding is wrong.

Thanks,
Soorya

Answer (score 4):

Using Cordova for Windows, I found out, that the App should be associated with an App in the Windows Store over menu command "Store" -> "Associate App with the Store...".

But even after "Store" -> "Associate App with the Store...", Push Messages failed to be delivered.

The issue was, that the App still had default CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx assigned.

After I've copied new CordovaApp.Windows_StoreKey.pfx to CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx message delivery succeed.

Comment: I have the same issue. Where did you get CordovaApp.Windows_StoreKey.pfx?

Comment: you get it into project folder, after  "Associate App with the Store..." procedure done.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested out the http://31daysofwindows8.com/push and it worked fine for me.   The cloud service does need the SID and key to authenticate with WNS on behalf of your application, so in that sense they are associated, but for the http://31daysofwindows8.com the association was quite temporary as you just enter them in as input (and be aware they are in clear text with that tool).

You would need to use the URI you got from your Windows 8 app (via [CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.pushnotifications.pushnotificationchannelmanager.createpushnotificationchannelforapplicationasync.aspx)) using *exactly* the same SID and key that you are using to obtain the OAuth access token.  All that would be appropriately setup for you when you associated that app with the profile in your store dashboard.

It sounds like this is just what you did, but the error you're getting has the hallmark of trying to use a channel URI obtained with one SID/Key to send a notification authenticated with a different SID/Key.  Note that if you're uninstalling and reinstalling your Win 8 app (an option on the Debug tab in Visual Studio), this will also invalidate a previously obtained URI; however, in my case, the 31daysofwindows8 site reported a revoked URI, not a "incompatible" one.

As for your cloud service that times out, are you url-encoding the URI when you send it up?

Lastly, it's a bit of a tangent from your specific question, but if you haven't looked at [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/), its role is precisely to take away the pain of rolling your own service to do all this.  There's a completely free tier and there's always the ability to add more horsepower when your app goes wildly successful.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for the response. I created a new SID and Secret for the app and associated it with the store. I now get the PUSH notification when i use http://31daysofwindows8.com/push. That's a relief.

Comment: But when i try to create a cloud service on my own, it always times out when I try to get the access token by passing the SID and secretKey. Any suggestions?

Comment: OAuthToken GetAccessToken(string secret, string sid)
{
var urlEncodedSid = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Format("{0}", sid));
var urlEncodedSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(secret);
var body = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com", urlEncodedSid, urlEncodedSecret);
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
string response = client.UploadString("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf", body);
var oAuthToken = GetOAuthTokenFromJson(response);
return oAuthToken;
}