# Device not receiving C# Windows Push Notifications because channel url incompatible

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

After many hours of trial, I still fail to send push notifications to my app. This is what I did so far:

- Activate the service at `https://appdev.microsoft.com`
- Got the SID, lets call it `ms-app://s-1-23-4-12345678901-...-12345678901`
- Received the client secret, lets call it `12Lwq7526OqNY8iN-aLkwds23451345`
- In my app I implented the following at some point (simplified):

  ```
  PushNotificationChannel channel = null;
  channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(channel.Uri);
  ```
- This prints an url of that kind:

  ```
  https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AgY7AABrfRCVgRV%2ba4DwoDjC2omrnOVwCkdhCrrzlJi6UpIwHzcig6%2fG5xZfnDqU0%2fXoE848ddiqyTaTlSSltp2Dn9Z3qaPsMAyh7kS%2bmlis1%2bwoh%2b%2b4DsAK1yeV1d9G1rUIuFs%3s
  ```
- I added correct package name, publisher display name and publisher ID to my Package.appxmanifest file
- So I thought I was ready for testing push notifications. Using my own implementation of push sharp, fiddler output is the following:

  **Request**:

  ```
  POST https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AgY7AABrfRCVgRV%2ba4DwoDjC2omrnOVwCkdhCrrzlJi6UpIwHzcig6%2fG5xZfnDqU0%2fXoE848ddiqyTaTlSSltp2Dn9Z3qaPsMAyh7kS%2bmlis1%2bwoh%2b%2b4DsAK1yeV1d9G1rUIuFs%3s HTTP/1.1
  X-WNS-Type: wns/toast
  Authorization: Bearer EgAC4AA1hAZAQMAklDAAEgAAAUe8/AGsK8a/yk78/WEDQf+KUld/nYIvJ51OIoCPgAfwqbl0oo1sPDLhd9ChiO/iLFVzwlTPE3trp9oTkJxNXi0yUrf+FKjRciq7Utek9B/4dxH9lFNy0R5iwdMS0xNS0yLTIyNDgyMDE1NzEtMjczODcxMjkyMy0yMzM3MbsS59ZuQmXCIAFoOiAAAAAAAgzMOTB7OuFIezrhS60gEAAoANS45LjYuMTBiPoPMh3Nj5MAEOp0RhrcMUx6D50AtDuzWE1AAAAAABeAG1zLWiwcDovL3MtTk2Nzk3LTEzOTYwNDkxODYtMjEyODYwMTQ3MS04MDg1MDg2ODUtMzY3NjQyNTk3OQA=
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Host: db3.notify.windows.com
  Content-Length: 138

  <toast>
    <visual>
      <binding template="ToastText01">
        <text id="1">This is a test</text>
      </binding>
    </visual>
  </toast>
  ```

  **Answer**

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
  Content-Length: 0
  X-WNS-ERROR-DESCRIPTION: Channel URL incompatible with caller app
  X-WNS-MSG-ID: 5FC550364E079585
  X-WNS-DEBUG-TRACE: DB3WNS4011533
  Date: Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:58:22 GMT
  ```
- I found this post [Channel URL incompatible with caller app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115257/channel-url-incompatible-with-caller-app) so far which was not really helping

I get the same error using the web service of http://31daysofwindows8.com/push. What can I do here? What could have gone wrong? Please note that this app has not been published yet to the store and I am testing on my local Windows 8.1 installation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wow, this is unbelievable. I nearly went nuts, but here is the solution (and explanation):

In the windows app dashboard it says that you can set your app identity manually or automatically. I chose to do it manually (I mean, why not?). But that was a mistake. I quote from microsoft.com dashboard:

---

**Set your app's identity values manually**

Open your app's AppManifest.xml file in a text editor and set these attributes of the  element using the values shown here.

```
<Identity Name=" MyName.MyApp " Publisher="CN=*******-****-****-****-************" />
```

---

This method did not let me receive push notifications!

The only way to get push notifications (for me) was the following: Try to set the app identity automatically by Visual Studio by calling this menu:

`PROJECT -> STORE -> ASSOCIATE APP WITH THE STORE...`

This solved my problem.

Comment: You are my hero! Tried to get this to work for almost two days. I´m so glad that I finally arrived on that post. 20 sec later it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: hi, I am not getting "PROJECT -> STORE -> ASSOCIATE APP WITH THE STORE.." in my visual studio 2012. can any one help?

Comment: @Naitik You need to be singed into VS with the Microsoft account that you created your app with before the option is available. You also need the app project selected in the VS solution explorer. If you have the root solution highlighted it will not be available.

Comment: Thank you for reply @robasaurus i start using vs2013 and i got this option.

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to use the "Associate App" approach because the customer wasn't comfortable with giving us their credentails.

What worked for me was to remove the following two elements from the .csproj file of the app:

```
<PackageCertificateKeyFile>...</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
<PackageCertificateThumbprint>...</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
```

Do that by either dragging the file into a text editor or unloading the project (using right click) and editing it using the xml editor (again in the context menu).

These elements might have snuck in when we associated our app with our testing app and stayed there when we removed the association and just set the identity as described by andreas.

```
<Identity Name="..." Publisher="CN=..." />
```

Edit: Just found out that doing this might break msbuild scripts that build packages. However, building app packages once within Visual Studio created new versions of these elements which then worked for me.

Comment: Well spotted, `<PackageCertificateKeyFile>` tags prevented notifications being received from any other developer debugging our solution with the error message `The Token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong`

Comment: After deleting the <PackageCertificateKeyFile> and <PackageCertificateThumbprint> and manually editing the Package.appxmanifest file, my app is still getting 403 forbiddden error. Anything else needs to be done, in addition to above?

Comment: @Tulika That's all that was needed for us, sorry. I recommend to get a second pair of eyes to check your Identity tag.

Answer (score 1):

MS documents are a nightmare for me, finally I found what need to do is:

right click on your windows store app solution -> "Store" -> "Associate App with the Store..." -> choose your app name and follow the steps until message "successfully" -> rebuild and run

Despite edit manifest manually by strictly follow the documents, but apparently it's not complete enough.

Comment: Isn't that what I exactly posted below? ;-o

Answer (score 1):

Using Cordova for Windows, I found out, that even after "Associate App with the Store...", Push Messages failed to be delivered.

The issue was, that the App still had default CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx assigned.

After I've copied new CordovaApp.Windows_StoreKey.pfx to CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx message delivery succeed.

Comment: Where did you get this "new" pfx from?

Comment: it comes after  "Associate App with the Store..." procedure

Comment: Do you know in which directory the new pfx is created?

Comment: This is the best answer!